# EntityManager.find method leading to MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, ambiguous

When I execute `EntityManager.find()` the following exception is thrown:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
>   Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous

The class (Profile) I'm trying to find has a bi-directional one-to-one relationship with another entity class (Gallery). I'd appreciate help in understanding `why` this exception is thrown and `how` to resolve it. Below are the two entity classes:

```
public class Profile {
 ...
 private java.sql.Date date;
 private my.webapp.Gallery gallery;
 ...

 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="gallery_id")
 public my.webapp.Gallery getGallery() {
   return gallery
 }
 ...
}

public class Gallery {
 ...
 private my.webapp.Profile profile;
 ...

 @OneToOne(mappedBy="gallery")
 public my.webapp.Profile getProfile() {
   return profile
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Fact: `date` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Look like that Hibernate/JPA didn't escape it (I would wonder why not). Turn on SQL logging and verify if the generated SQL is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because "date" is a reserved keyword? Try adding this to the "date" property (or getter). It will quote the property name.

```
@Column(name="`date`")
```

Comment: No, `DATE` is not a reserved word (at least, not anymore).